# Large white-space between first and second Bootstrap table column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I remove the large white space between the Name column and the first date column containing 24?

It looks to be caused by the Bootstrap CSS but I'm not sure why.

The issue goes away based on my underlying model when there are more dates available in the calendar but I'm struggling to figure out why.

```css
#container-body {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

#locala-oc {
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

table.dt-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination {
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #792273;
}

.form-text-bottom {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

thead.remove-header-top > tr > th {
  border-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

tr.table-striped-odd {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.validation-summary-errors ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.stock-card {
  height: 220px;
}

.stock-card-header {
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#calendar th,
#calendar td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#calendar th.name,
#calendar td.name {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.calendar-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

#calendar {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#calendar col.day,
#calendar th.day,
#calendar td.day {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#calendar > thead > tr > th.weekend,
#calendar > tbody > tr > td.weekend {
  background: lightgray;
}

#calendar > tbody > tr > td.user-rt {
  background-color: #792273;
}

#calendar > tbody > tr > td.user-al {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

#calendar > tbody > tr > td.user-rt.user-al {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%, red), color-stop(50%, green));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="calendar-wrapper">
  <table id="calendar" class="table table-bordered">
    <colgroup>
      <col class="name">
        <col class="day" data-date="20171124">
          <col class="day weekend" data-date="20171125">
            <col class="day weekend" data-date="20171126">
              <col class="day" data-date="20171127">
                <col class="day" data-date="20171128">
                  <col class="day" data-date="20171129">
                    <col class="day" data-date="20171130">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="name">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="7">November 2017</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="name">Name</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171124">24</th>
        <th class="day weekend" data-date="20171125">25</th>
        <th class="day weekend" data-date="20171126">26</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171127">27</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171128">28</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171129">29</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171130">30</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">User A</td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171124" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day weekend user-rt" data-date="20171125" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day weekend user-rt" data-date="20171126" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171127" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171128" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171129" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171130" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you use position:absolute to #calendar th.name, #calendar td.name?

Comment: So that column remains visible when scrolling horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `table` has a width of 100%. Change that to `width: auto`

```css
#container-body {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

#locala-oc {
  height: 30px;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

table.dt-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination {
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #792273;
}

.form-text-bottom {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

thead.remove-header-top > tr > th {
  border-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

tr.table-striped-odd {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.validation-summary-errors ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.stock-card {
  height: 220px;
}

.stock-card-header {
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#calendar th,
#calendar td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#calendar th.name,
#calendar td.name {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.calendar-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

#calendar {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#calendar col.day,
#calendar th.day,
#calendar td.day {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#calendar > thead > tr > th.weekend,
#calendar > tbody > tr > td.weekend {
  background: lightgray;
}

#calendar > tbody > tr > td.user-rt {
  background-color: #792273;
}

#calendar > tbody > tr > td.user-al {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

#calendar > tbody > tr > td.user-rt.user-al {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%, red), color-stop(50%, green));
}

.table{
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="calendar-wrapper">
  <table id="calendar" class="table table-bordered">
    <colgroup>
      <col class="name">
        <col class="day" data-date="20171124">
          <col class="day weekend" data-date="20171125">
            <col class="day weekend" data-date="20171126">
              <col class="day" data-date="20171127">
                <col class="day" data-date="20171128">
                  <col class="day" data-date="20171129">
                    <col class="day" data-date="20171130">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="name">&nbsp;</th>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="7">November 2017</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="name">Name</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171124">24</th>
        <th class="day weekend" data-date="20171125">25</th>
        <th class="day weekend" data-date="20171126">26</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171127">27</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171128">28</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171129">29</th>
        <th class="day" data-date="20171130">30</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="name">User A</td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171124" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day weekend user-rt" data-date="20171125" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day weekend user-rt" data-date="20171126" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171127" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171128" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171129" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="day user-rt" data-date="20171130" data-userid="1873">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That does works but the columns are no longer equally sized to 40px, is there an alternative?